# Android FFMPEG doesn't recognize file: protocol

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I'm running an android ffmpeg build through the Runtime.getRuntime().exec() command
Problem is that when i specify the input as a file i get this error:

```
E/MainActivity(18168): file:/mnt/sdcard/young.flv: Protocol not found
```

Initially i just specified the file name without the "file:" prefix and still get the same error. How can i specify input files?

Comment: try /mnt/sdcard/young.flv without file: prefix

Comment: i already tried doing it without the file: prefix and didnt work. That's why i added it.

Comment: Do you enable READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE for your application ?

Comment: Hi qrtt1, i do have the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, I have figured out what the problem was, see my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so apparently my ffmpeg build didnt have "file" listed when i run "ffmpeg -protocols". So I added --enable-protocol=file to configure and rebuilt ffmpeg. Now it can accept file inputs without even adding the "file:" prefix